# Laravel simple form not setting errors and session variables

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to create a simple form that adds a record into a database table (that has 2 fields: ID and name).

Here is the code I have so far:

*routes.php*

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/banks/add', 'BanksController@add');
    Route::post('/banks/add', 'BanksController@store');
});
```

*BanksController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\BankFormRequest;
use App\Bank;

class BanksController extends Controller
{

    public function add() {
        return view('banks.add');
    }

    public function store(BankFormRequest $request) {

        $bank = new Bank(array(
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
        ));
        $bank->save();

        return redirect('/banks/add')->with('status', 'Your bank has been created! Its name is: '.$request->get('name'));
    }

}
```

*BankFormRequest.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class BankFormRequest extends Request
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:banks|max:255',
        ];
    }

}
```

*Bank.php*

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bank extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

*banks/add.php*

```
<form id="registerForm" role="form" method="post">
    <pre><?=var_dump($errors)?></pre>
    <pre>
        <?php if (session()->has('status')): ?>
            <?=session('status')?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </pre>

    <?php if (isset($errors) && $errors->any()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($errors->all() as $error): ?>
            <p class="alert alert-danger"><?=$erorr?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?=csrf_token()?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bank name" name="name">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

*banks table*

```
CREATE TABLE `banks` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

In the banks/add view I have the form and 2 var_dumps of the $errors and session('status') variables, but they are always NULL. Otherwise, the form validator works well and it inserts my input into the database if it passes the rules I defined.

Anyone knows what causes my errors to not be shown?

Comment: Please, post the of your `view` file and `table` structure. Also post the error messages.

Comment: I edited my post. I don't get any errors. Everything works as intended only that my errors or success message isn't displayed because the variables are always empty.

Comment: You didn't import `use Session;` in your controller. Try this.

Comment: I tried but it didn't change anything. Sessions are loaded anyway in the app/Http/Kernel.php file inside the middleware groups, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your banks/add.php

```
<p class="alert alert-danger"><?=$erorr?></p>
```

**$erorr** is wrong

Comment: Thanks. However it still doesn't fix my problem. I even tried to dump the errors array like this `<?=var_dump($errors->all())?>` and it's always empty.

Comment: Yeah. Now it works for me too. Do you know which is the explanation? I was reading [here](http://learninglaravel.net/laravel5/building-a-support-ticket-system) in the "A note about Laravel 5.2's changes" section that _$errors object is only available when you put the related route inside the web middleware group_.

Comment: no sorry, they made some changes https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/web-middleware-in-laravel-52

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel 5.2 try to remove web middleware on the route group this will fix your problem. why? because the RouteServiceProvider class will add it for you.

line 53 - 60 as of this writing.

```
  protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group([
            'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
        ], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }
```